# Merge cells in Vba based on another column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, merge

I currently am automating tasks on a recurring Excel Dashboard. All the data fills out according to what I want but I hit a roadblock when it comes to formatting the said dashboard. 
The idea would be to merge column F cells according to the values in `column C` cells. So far my code only merges the first 2 cells and the for loop keeps going without changing anything.

I have tried both a `For Loop` and a `Do until Isempty` loop to no avail.

```
Dim consumerwb As Workbook
Dim CellSlct As Range, cell As Range
Set consumerwb = Workbooks("Consumer_V2.xlsm")
consumerwb.Activate

Set CellSlct = Range("C6").End(xlDown)

Mergeagain:

On Error Resume Next

For Each cell In CellSlct
 If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
        Range(cell.Offset(0, 3), cell.Offset(1, 3)).Merge
        GoTo Mergeagain
 End If  
Next`
```

I want row `F` cells (empty) to be merged together according to the values of Row C:

```
C           D  E  F
customer1   X  X  Cst1
customer2   X  X  Cst2
customer2   X  X  (Merged with above, this is where my code stops merging)
customer2   X  X  (Merged with above)
customer3   X  X  Cst3
customer3   X  X  (Merged with above)
```

F column is completely empty, so far my code merges the first 2 reiterations of Customer2, stops working after that...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `Union` to create a range to merge before merging. Then use the function `Range.Merge` to merge them.
- This will work for a continuous range from `C6` as in the question. You can manipulate the code for your purpose.

**Try this:**

```
Sub Mrg()

Dim consumerwb As Workbook
Dim CellSlct As Range, cel As Range
Set consumerwb = Workbooks("Consumer_V2.xlsm")
consumerwb.Activate

Set CellSlct = Range("C6").Offset(0, 3)

For Each cel In Range("C7:C" & Range("C6").End(xlDown).row)

    If cel.Value = cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
       Set CellSlct = Union(CellSlct, cel.Offset(0, 3))
    Else
        CellSlct.Merge
        Set CellSlct = cel.Offset(0, 3)
    End If

Next

CellSlct.Merge

End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]